# How can I run a Postgres function from ZF1?

Tags: postgresql, function, zend-framework

I am trying to run a **Postgres function** from a **ZF1** project, but I was unable ton find any useful tip on Google.

I tried running it via the `$db->query()` method, to no avail.

Thank you !

Comment: I have no idea about ZF1, but in Postgres you simply use `select function_name()` to "run" a function. I'm sure you can run such a simple query with your framework.

Comment: I would start here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens There is nothing on this page about running a PG function, I already checked. Using the CRUD adds the FROM keyword that makes the query fail.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, that's it ! I had an error with my SELECT, but it wxas because of the FROM I put...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name, here is the answer :

```
SELECT function_name()
```

We no `FROM`, or you'll have an error as I had !

Comment: You need a `from` if the function is defined as `returns setof ...` or `returns table (...)`. If the function only returns a single value (e.g. `returns integer`)  you must not use a `from`